# What is the range of the derivative of $g(x) = f(x)/(x+1)$, where $f(x)$ is differentiable on $x\in[0,5]$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $g(x) = f(x)/(x+1)$, where $f(x)$ is differentiable on $x\in[0,5]$, such that $f(0)=4$ and $f(5)=-1$. What is the range of values $g'(c)$ for a $c$ belonging to $[0,5]$?

Considering values of $f(x_i)$, $f(x)$ must decrease at least once from $0$ to $5$. But that is all the information I can use here. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: You can get the $\in$-sign by typing `\in` in mathmode. If you are ever unsure how to type something here, just take a look at [this.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Yes, it looks as if a supplementary hypothesis is missing. I have tried the following function defined by $f_a(x)=u = a x(x - 2.5) + 4 - x$ depending on parameter $a$ and fulfilling the hypothesis. But according to the value of $a$, the values taken by the derivative of $g$ can be arbitrarily large.   One thing also, you have, I think to assume that $f$ \in C^1$, not simply derivable.

Comment: \begin{equation}g'(x)=\frac{(x+1)f'(x)-f(x)}{(x+1)^{2}}\end{equation}

For a concretely given $c$, we have:

\begin{equation}g'(c)=\frac{(c+1)f'(c)-f(c)}{(c+1)^{2}}\end{equation}

For the range of all $c\in [0,5]$, the answer depends on the range of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ in the interval $x\in [0,5]$.

Answer (score 1):

This question indeed seems to be incomplete. For instance, if there exists a 
$c\in(0,5)$ such that $$c=\dfrac{-1+2f'(c)\pm\sqrt{4\big(f'(c)\big)^2-8f''(c)f(c)} }{2f''(c)}$$ then $g'(x)$ attains a local maximum on $(0,5)$. To know if this is the case we need way more information on $f$.

If we were given, that $f$ is twice differentiable on $[0,5]$, then we could use the above to conclude at least that the range of $g'$ is bounded. But as I said, this question does not seem solvable, with the information we're given.